# node/express.js - ip address is undefined randomly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Platform - node.js(v0.10.32)/express.js(v3)

I am using the following code to determine the ip address of the user:

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
    req.connection.remoteAddress ||
    req.socket.remoteAddress ||
    req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

when I run my app in localhost, the value returned is 127.0.0.1. But every now and then, very randomly, I get undefined value from the above code. This is part of my app security check and when it fails the user gets logged out. Am I missing anything here? Please help.

Comment: I am seeing this a lot too